# Scala code changes for algorithm

Tags: arrays, string, algorithm, scala

I have the following Scala code in which z represents array of strings with each string representing a datapoint of a dataset. 
The first step is to calculate the matching score between first string in dataset with all the other strings in the dataset, after that store all the similar strings in one set.
The second step would be to calculate matching score of the second string that doesn't match in the first step with all the other unmatched strings in the dataset.
The third and consequent steps goes like the previous steps. 
The most important thing is I have to care that all the strings that are matching in the above processes doesn't participate in further loops as they have been matched in the previous steps. 
Suggest changes in the code so that all my above requirements are met.

```
val z = y.split("\n")       // z is Array[String]

for (i <- 1 to 500)
{

var str = ArrayBuffer[String]()
   str += z(i)

 for(j <- 1 to 500)
 {         

   val dist = match(z(i),z(j))  // match calculates score between 2 strings 

    if (dist < threshold){

        str += z(j)     
 }
}
```

Comment: You might want to try codereview.stackexchange for 'suggestions'

Comment: @ShreyansSheth Code Review doesn't offer suggestions to change how the code works, it's just for reviewing code that already works as intended.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Scalish approach that may convey the intended semantics, like this

```
val xs = y.split("\n")
val res = 
  for { zi <- xs
        zj <- xs
        if score(zi,zj) < threshold
      }
  yield zj

res.mkString
```

Namely, for each `zi` and each `zj` in the splat string, filter those pairs whose scoring is lesser than a `threshold`, and then yield the second item from each pair.

Note this requires no indexed references or mutable collections.